# Enabled all the IIS settings but IIS still not showing on the taskbar

Tags: iis

Had a look at minimizing and maximizing the screen and am still unable to see the IIS console.

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components#registry-keys Please check registry keys to see what exactly you have installed. "showing on the taskbar" was never a valid indicator.

Comment: Restart your computer and check agai, and go to the control panel -> programs -> programs and features to check if iis is successfully installed.

Comment: @LexLi I can see it on that taskbar after trying to open it.

Comment: @samwu Had a look at the application all looks well

Comment: If you resolved it on your own, post and accept your own answer below, not edit the question body.

Comment: **Resolution**

Thanks all for the answers, It looks like it was hiding on another screen.

To fix this I had to change to Tablet MODE for the console to actually appear the after it appear i turned off Tablet Mode, then all is Good

@LexLi sorry, learnt something new again today. wont happen again